# How to write a tail -f like C program

Tags: c, linux

I want to implement a C program in Linux (Ubuntu distro) that mimics `tail -f`. Note that I do not want to actually call `tail -f` from my C code, rather implement its behaviour. At the moment I can think of two ways to implement it.

1. When the program is called, I seek to the end of file. Afterwards, I would read to the end of file periodically and print whatever I read if it is not empty.
2. The second method which can potentially be more efficient is to again, seek to the end of file. But, this time I "somehow" listen for changes to that file and read to the end of file, only if I it is changed.

With that being said, my question is how to implement the second approach and if someone can share if it is worth the effort. Also, are these the only two options?

NOTE: Thanks for the comments, the question is changed based on them.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about `tail -f` (which is quite different from the question you link to)?

Comment: You might want to google "inotify" - it's a facility for monitoring files (or directories).

Comment: @rici tail -f does what I want. But I do not want to call a bash command from my C code.

Comment: Why down vote? Please share your reason, instead of simply down voting.

Comment: @Z0lenDer: Then the title doesn't say it all, because it doesn't mention that you want to implement the behaviour of `tail` with the `-f` flag. The question in your link is talking about a different feature of tail (finding the last `n` lines of a file), so it is not explicit what you are really asking about. By the way, there is no cross-platform way to "listen for changes in the watched file", so if you want to do that, you need to implement it differently on different platforms. Whether that is worth doing is a matter of opinion and hence out of scope for SO.

Comment: @rici You are right. miy question is not clear. I will rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standardized mechanism for monitoring changes to a file, so you'll need to implement a "polling" solution anyway (that is, when you hit the end of file, wait a  short amount of time and try again.)

On Linux, you can use the `inotify` family of system calls, but be aware that it won't always work. It doesn't work for special files or remote filesystems, for example, and it may not work for some local filesystems. It is complicated in the case of symlinks. And so on. There is a Windows equivalent, but I believe it suffers from some of the same issues.

So even if you use a notification system, you'll need the polling solution as a backup, and since OS notifications are not guaranteed to be reliable (that is, if the system is under load, notifications might be dropped), you'll need to poll on timeout even if you are using a notification system.

You might want to take a look at the implementation of the GNU `tail` utility (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) to see how the special cases are handled.

Comment: Isn't `tail` part of `coreutils`? Anyways, you might as well analyze `tail` through `strace`.

Comment: @black: Yes it is, which is why the URL for tail.c is in the `coreutils.git` repository :) You could analyze tail with strace for a particular file and a particular set of circumstances, but if you want to see all the possibilities it considers -- which is what you would need to do if you wanted to reimplement it -- reading the code is probably more informative. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the requirement by following steps:
1) fopen with 'a+' mode;
2) select the file discriptor opened (need do convert from FILE * to file descriptor) and do the read.